# AJAX NumericUpDownExtender and TextBox width trouble

Tags: asp.net, ajax

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Font-Size="12pt" Width="92px">10</asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" runat="server"
 TargetControlID="TextBox5">
</ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender>
```

So... problem is : My TexBox5 becomes very small at width and it doesn't care what width I setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cc1:NumericUpDownExtender ID="txtEgitimSuresi_NumericUpDownExtender" 
            runat="server" Enabled="True" Maximum="100" 
            Minimum="0" RefValues="" ServiceDownMethod="" 
            ServiceDownPath="" ServiceUpMethod="" Tag="" TargetButtonDownID="" 
            TargetButtonUpID="" TargetControlID="txtEgitimSuresi" Width="111">
        </cc1:NumericUpDownExtender>
```

Try to give a value to width property of NumericUpDownExtender.

Answer (score 1):

It will ignore Width. Try use cols.

Comment: cols... ? on text box ? can you share an example ?

Comment: <input type="text" cols="40" /> So that is what you need to get it bigger in pure HTML. To get the asp:TextBox to render that is another question. I am not sure if it has a cols property like so: <asp:TextBox cols="40" runat ... />. I think it might be minlength. If that doesn't work try using the style property. Sorry I am not near an IDE so I can't figure it out right now.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is actually Columns. Do you not have intellisense? The first that came up as I typed cols in the <asp:TextBox> tag was Columns.

Answer (score 0):

Give width="100" to NumericUpDownExtender